# Isomorphism between any finite group and a subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I am trying to prove:

> Prove that every finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ for some $n$.

Here is my attempt, which is my attempt at trying to understand a proof in a set of algebra lecture notes I found.

> For each $g \in G$, define the map
> \begin{align*}
> m_g: \underset{x}{G} \underset{\longmapsto}{\to} \underset{gx}{G}. 
> \end{align*}
> I claim that $m_g \in \mathrm{Perm}(G)$, i.e., that $m_G$ is a bijection of sets. Given $a,b \in G$ for which $m_g (a) = m_g (b)$, we have $ga = gb$, so by left cancellation, we have $a = b$, so $m_g$ is injective. Furthermore, given $h \in G$, we have $m_g\left(g^{-1} h\right) = g\left(g^{-1} h\right) = h$, so $m_g$ is surjective and hence bijective. Next, define the map
> \begin{align*}
> \varphi: \underset{g}{G} \underset{\longmapsto}{\to} \underset{m_g}{\mathrm{Perm}(G)},
> \end{align*}
> First, we show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, i.e., that given $g,h \in G$, we have $\varphi(gh) = \varphi(g) \varphi(h)$, which is equivalent to proving that $m_{gh} = m_g m_h$. For any $x \in G$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> m_{gh} (x) = (gh)x = g(hx) = m_g (hx) = m_g \left(m_h (x)\right) = m_g \circ m_h (x),
> \end{align*}
> So $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism, as desired. Next, we show that $\varphi$ is injective. Given $g, g' \in G$ for which $g \neq g'$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> m_g (e) = ge = g \neq g' = g'e = m_{g'} (e),
> \end{align*}
> so $\varphi(g) \neq \varphi(g')$. This implies that $G \cong \mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$. Indeed, the map $f: G \to \mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$ sending $g \to \varphi(g)$ gives an isomorphism of groups. If $h \in \mathrm{Im}(\varphi$, then there exists a unique $g \in G$ such that $\varphi(g) = h$, so we have $f(g) = \varphi(g) = h$, so $f$ is surjective. Given $a,b \in G$ for which $f(a) = f(b)$, we have $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b)$, which implies that $a = b$ by injectivity of $\varphi$, so $f$ is injective and hence bijective. Finally, if $a,b \in G$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> f(ab) = \varphi(ab) = \varphi(a) \varphi(b) = f(a) f(b),
> \end{align*}
> since $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism. Clearly, $\mathrm{Im}(\varphi) \subset \mathrm{Perm}(G)$. Furthermore, $\mathrm{Perm}(G) \cong S_n$.
> Therefore, we conclude
> \begin{align*}
>  G \cong \mathrm{Im}(\varphi) \subset \mathrm{Perm}(G) \cong S_n,
>  \end{align*}
> as desired.

There are two things I have doubts about.

First, I haven't proved that $G$ is ismorphism to a subgroup of $S_n$, but to a subgroup of $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$. Since $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ and $S_n$ are isomorphic, I can view $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ as a subgroup of $S_n$. Is this the correct idea? Alternatively, since $\mathrm{Perm}(G) \to S_n$, there exists an isomorphism $\Phi$ between the two, and if $\mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$, then the image of this subgroup under the ismorphism $\Phi$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Second, I can't manage to prove that $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ and $S_n$ are isomorphic. In particular, I'm having trouble understanding the differences between them. $\mathrm{Perm}(G)$ is the set of maps $f: G \to G$ that are bijective and $S_n$ is the set of permutations of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. If I label the elements of $G$ as $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, then these are clearly the same set, up to labelling, but I don't know how to prove that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first question, the answer is affirmative: since $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$ and $S_n$ are isomorphic, you can view $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$ as a subgroup of $S_n$.

On the the other hand, given any two sets $A$ and $B$ for which there is a bejection $\psi\colon A\longrightarrow B$, the groups $\operatorname{Perm}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Perm}(B)$; just take$$\begin{array}{rccc}\varphi\colon&\operatorname{Perm}(A)&\longrightarrow&\operatorname{Perm}(B)\\&\eta&\mapsto&\psi\circ\eta\circ\psi^{-1}.\end{array}$$In particular, since $S_n=\operatorname{Perm}(\{1,2,\ldots,n\})$, if $G$ has $n$ elements, then $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$ and $S_n$ are isomorphic.

Comment: I assume we take $A = \mathrm{Perm}(1, 2, \ldots, n)$ and $B = S_n$? Could you explain what the $f$ is that you used in your function definition?

Comment: Yes to the first question. And that $f$ was a typo; I meant $\psi$.

Comment: "Yes to the first question": ?

Comment: @rhesu Oops. Right. I was too fast here.

Comment: I'd have said $A=G$ and $B=\{1,\dots,n\}$ (or possibly vice versa, this is not key), where $n:=|G|$, isn't it?

Comment: @rhesu Again, yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user861776 Concerning your first question from the comment, the answer is negative. What I had in mind was $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $B=G$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you very much. I've been working through this more, and I was able to prove that this map you defined is a homomorphism and an injection, but I can't prove directly that it's a surjection. Do you have any tips for how to prove that?

Comment: @user861776, for every $\sigma\in\operatorname{Perm}(B)$, it turns out that $\sigma=\varphi(\psi^{-1}\sigma\psi)$.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Last question I have (if that's ok): this map works perfectly, but how would one come up with this? Conjugation is surely an. isomorphism, and elements of $S_n$ are stable under conjugation. Is that where it comes from?

Comment: The map $\psi$ identifies each element $a\in A$ with an element $\psi(a)\in B$. And the map $\psi^{-1}$ identifies each element $b\in B$ with an element $\psi^{-1}(b)\in A$. So, if you have a permutation $\eta$ of $A$, you can build a permutation of $B$ as follows: you take $b\in B$; then $b$ is identified with $\psi^{-1}(b)\in A$. Then you compute $\eta\bigl(\psi^{-1}(b)\bigr)$, which gives you another element of $A$. And finally you identify it with $\psi\bigl(\eta\bigl(\psi^{-1}(b)\bigr)\bigr)\in B$. That's how that map was imagined.

Answer (score 1):

This is Cayley's theorem for finite groups  (it actually works on infinite groups too).

The symmetric group $S_n $ is precisely the group of permutations of an $n $-element set.  If you insist on distinguishing between them, like if you take a different  $n $- element set than $\{1,2,\dots,n\} $,  then there certainly is a bijective homomorphism  (that's an isomorphism) between them. (And as I still recall my friend Dan Upper saying during my Berkeley days,  once two things are isomorphic you can kiss it goodbye,  that's stop thinking about them as different objects.)

Comment: I agree completely that they're intuitively isomorphic, and indexing $G$ by the numbers $1, \ldots, n$ makes that even clearer, but I'm having trouble proving it formally.

Comment: C'mon,  we can use the bijection between  $\{1,2,\dots,n\} $ and $\{m_1,\dots, m_n\} $ given by the rule $i\mapsto m_i $.  Then they're isomorphic as sets.  Then, just compose with any $\phi\in S_n$ for your isomorphism.   This is straight forward.

Comment: The details are in @José's answer.  But you're right,  it's a subtle point.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, but could you explain what you mean by "just compose with any $\phi \in S_n$?" I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Well, that's where I over-simplified ever so slightly.   As @José wrote, you technically compose with the isomorphism between the finite sets, and post-compose with its inverse,  to make everything work out. With practice this'll become clearer.

Comment: Remember a permutation is just a bijection.   So you end up with a composition of three bijections.  That's a bijection.   Hence a permutation. Next you would need to check that the map so defined is an isomorphism.   (It's clear that it is though. )  So again I'm having to admit there are a few hidden details.